# How to find the position of an element and apply it to a different element?

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I have a star icon on a page. If the user is not logged in, I'm displaying another image which says "Please sign in". The problem I'm having is this image get's displayed in the next line all the way to left. I need to show it right below the star icon. I'm trying to find the position of the star icon, then adjust the top and bottom values and have the "Please sign in" image show right below it.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgFavorite" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
<div id="toolTipDivTitle" class="tooltip"></div>
```

And my javascript -

```
 function showSignInPromptForTitle() {
    var toolTipDivTitle = $("#toolTipDivTitle");
    toolTipDivTitle.css('background', 'url(/SiteCollectionImages/CF_HoverOver.png) no-repeat');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('color', 'white');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('width', '160px');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('height', '83px');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('padding', '30px 5px 0px 20px');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('z-index', '9999');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('display', 'none');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('position', 'absolute');
    toolTipDivTitle.css('font-size', '11px');
    toolTipDivTitle.text('Sign in to add to your favorites.');
    toolTipDivTitle.show();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Update: Here's the fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/eqACv/2/

Comment: Please stick that jQuery object to a variable.

$tooltip = $("#toolTipDivTitle");

and always refer to that variable from that point on (inside that function), you will save resources this way.

Comment: Yeah, I still need to refactor the code in this page but thanks for pointing it. Edit: Changed it in the post.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML and CSS, preferrably in a fiddle?  While js or Jquery can do this, there is probably a small issue with the CSS best fixed there.  (Seems like a float is off or a margin out of whack).  Also, as you are not manipulating the CSS for the tooltip, you should place that all in your stylesheet and shrink the js.

Comment: @Jose: Better, (a) use call chaining and (b) send an object to `.css`. Your function `showSignInPromptForTitle` can be a single statement.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sure, I would also write it completely different... just wanted to have a cleaner code easier to read.

Comment: @Jason Here's the Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/eqACv/2/
@Jose & @Tomalak, I'm still learning jQuery and this is just my test page. Thanks for letting me know how to optimize the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with what you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/eqACv/8/

For an even greater effect you should add ('blind',500) as parameters for the functions hide and show.(Requires jQuery UI)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one_element').offset( $('#another_element').offset() );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/position/

http://api.jquery.com/offset

Check those, they behave differently.